# 10 seconds of delay to access to a local MySQL Docker

Tags: networking, virtualbox, mysql, docker

I got a VirtualBox VM from a coworker that he set up with vagrant (though I only launch the VM via VirtualBox and log as `vagrant` with `vagrant` as a password).

In this VM, he set up a dev' environnement for one of our application. The network configuration of the VM is like so:

- Adapter 1: NAT
- Adapter 2: Host-only adapter (vboxnet0 - basic settings, without DHCP)

Inside this VM there is a MySQL docker launched via the `.bashrc` (`docker start mysql > /dev/null 2>&1`), this docker is used by our application. The problem is, whatever I want to do with that MySQL, it took exactly 10 seconds to connect to it (even with just a `telnet`). Have you any idea where could be the problem? I join to this question any data that could be relevant to help me. Thank you in advance.

A look of my /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.56.101
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.56.0
broadcast 192.168.56.255
```

When I do a `route -n`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.56.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

And a `ifconfig`:

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 56:84:7a:fe:97:99  
          inet addr:172.17.42.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5484:7aff:fefe:9799/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:536 (536.0 B)  TX bytes:648 (648.0 B)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:1d:ae:8b  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe1d:ae8b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:391 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:406 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:39758 (39.7 KB)  TX bytes:35582 (35.5 KB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:57:d0:a2  
          inet addr:192.168.56.101  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe57:d0a2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:60 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:13376 (13.3 KB)  TX bytes:1276 (1.2 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:22 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:22 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1472 (1.4 KB)  TX bytes:1472 (1.4 KB)

veth493bc8d Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 7a:ac:69:9c:1a:b6  
          inet6 addr: fe80::78ac:69ff:fe9c:1ab6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:1296 (1.2 KB)
```

**Edit:** Also, my `/etc/hosts` (`******` represents some of our sub-domaines.domains):
    127.0.0.1 localhost

```
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
172.16.200.11 *********.********.fr

127.0.0.1 mysql
127.0.0.1 postgresql

127.0.0.1 *********.**********.com
127.0.0.1 *********.**********.com
```

Comment: what does the dns and /etc/hosts file look like ? Delays like that are often dns timeouts in my experience.

Comment: That also what I think, because this is a fixed delay. I've added my `/etc/hosts` to my original question. I don't think DNS matters since I directly use the IP (either `127.0.0.1` or the IP of the docker, I always got the delay).